# How to only get certain data from API JSON response data

Tags: json, api

I am very new to JS and JSON, I've looked for a while and I can't seem to find the answer. I'm trying to use this API that returns two properties, as seen in the code block below,

```
{
"quote": "Innovation distinguishes between a leader and a follower.",
"name": "Steve Jobs"
}
```

It only returns those 2 values and they are randomized each time. Using JS, how do I only grab the "quote" element each time.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result['quote']
```

example

```
results = {
"quote": "Innovation distinguishes between a leader and a follower.",
"name": "Steve Jobs"
}

console.log(results['quote'])
```

output

Innovation distinguishes between a leader and a follower.

Edit:

Now I won't be able to actually get the data from your website due to CORS

but you could use the fetch method for it

example

```
document.onLoad(fetch("https://michael-scott-quotes-api.herokuapp.com/randomQuote")
.then((response)=>{
    data = response.json();
    console.log(data)
})
)
```

and then you can use the above method to get the quote from it

this will on document load, fetch the data from API and then you can do what you want with it

Comment: Great thanks! How do I turn my results from the API into JSON like that? How do I turn www.example.com/quotes into JSON like that within JS?

Comment: how are the results from your api? i don't see anything at example.com/quotes

Comment: heres the actual endpoint https://michael-scott-quotes-api.herokuapp.com/randomQuote